# How to write test cases for Controller for RestAPI using Junit and Mockito when project does not have a service class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, mockito

***I am very new to `jUnit` and Mockito and `Springboot` and I try learning from tutorials. I want to write test cases for controller class, but I don't have a pojos class in my project.
I only have `daos`, `repository`, `controller` and `main class`. So, please can someone explain me with example.*

```
package com.example.spring;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.spring.User;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053469/unit-tests-how-to-mock-repository-using-mockito. you can mock the repositories and use the mock to validate and write your unit tests for controllers.

Comment: Can you please add some code so that we can create examples based on your code? Thanks!